# Please wait response?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, in-app-purchase

I am working on a project with Android In App Billing. Here is the flow I am trying to achieve:

### The user purchases an item -> I programmatically consume the item so that they can purchase it again -> the user purchases the item again.

However the problem I am facing, is that consuming the purchase with async task takes a few seconds, so the real flow is this:

**User purchases -> Programmatically consumed -> attempts to purchase the item again, but can't because the async to consume is still running, I receive an "Item already owned Error"**

Here is what I use to consume, and it takes a few seconds.

```
 this.mHelper.consumeAsync(this.i.getPurchase("donate_one_dollar"), new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase paramAnonymousPurchase, IabResult paramAnonymousIabResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thank you so much for your donation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

My question: Is there any way to show the user a "Please Wait" dialog or a prompt that shows that they're next purchase is being loaded? All I have is a consume finished listener, which doesn't seem to be enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProgressDialog to show "please wait" dialog like this:

```
//use it when you want to display the Dialog  

ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setTitle("please wait");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();

// use it to dismiss the dialog  
progressDialog.dismiss();
```